# jQuery add previous page h3 to current page input value

Tags: jquery, input

Is it possible to add the h3 from the previous page to the current page's input value?
I'm creating a form and want the first input value to be populated by the previous pages h3.

I have an unordered list, and each list item has a h3 which I want to populate the input value with, and each list item has a link to the form. So when that link to the form is clicked, the h3 from the list item is used to populate the input value.

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to pass the variable between pages using either cookies (which jQuery can do) or with serverside sessions (which jQuery can't).

Comment: What's wrong with passing it as a query string parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to access information, then it needs to be stored somewhere. You can store the data client-side or pass data through a link using a querystring or a hashtag.

**On origin page**

```
<a href="nextpage.php?h3=test">link</a>
```

**On receiving page, assuming PHP**

```
<?
$heading = $_GET['h3'];
php echo '<input type="text">'.$heading.'</input>';
?>
```

edit for comment: for silly aspers use google ;) http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp

Comment: @Terry I was in a hurry and took the first google hit for a topic on which I have no expertise (since the OP didn't tag .NET). Would you prefer [a link from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the value of the element from page to page, there are few ways to accomplish this:

In the **source** page:

- Query String

  ```
  myLink.NavigateUrl = "~/MyTargetPage.aspx?d=" + GetCurrentH3Value();
  ```
- Session

  ```
  Session["d"] = GetCurrentH3Value();
  ```
- Cookies

  ```
  Response.Cookies["d"].Value = GetCurrentH3Value();
  ```

In the **target** page:

- Query String

  ```
  var lastH3 = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["d"]);
  ```
- Session

  ```
  var lastH3 = Session["d"].ToString();
  ```
- Cookies

  ```
  var lastH3 = Request.Cookies["d"].Value;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Using just javascript (jQuery):

First create a function that reads the query string, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) has many examples.

Then:

**Source** page:

```
<ul id="listOfH3s">
   <li><h3>1</h3></li>
   <li><h3>2</h3></li>
   <li><h3>3</h3></li>
</ul>

$('#listOfH3s li').click(function() {
    window.location = 'mypage.aspx?h3=' + $(this).find('h3').text();
});
```

**Destination** page:

```
<input type="text" id="h3" />

$('#h3').val(getUrlParam('h3'));
```